# Windows form application - Icon image location?

Tags: icons

I think this should be a relatively easy one to answer, I hope, but is proving to be a bit of a stress!

I have used an Icon on an old application developed some years ago and I would now like to use the icon for a current project.. however..

I added the icon using the upload/import icon-image in the properties window, and did not add it in the project resources file, nor specify its location anywhere in my code, using only the icon tool in the properties window.

Now wanting to find the icon image file to use again, I cannot find it anywhere! I have trawled through all the project files looking for the image file or a ref to its location, but have found nothing; except for:

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

When running the application the icon is still clearly visible in the applications taskbar tile.

Does anyone know where the icon file is stored / how I can retrieve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what language was the orginal project in??

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/109347/extract-high-quality-icons-from-files-using-a-free-tool/ I would just get a tool similar to the one in the article and just extract it.

Comment: Hi.. it was C#.. I will try the extractor now, thanks. I will report back shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately that extractor didn't work for me. It was just showing a lot of what appeared to be windows system file icons, but none from my application. I came across this piece of code: ""this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);"" but not sure how it works, as it threw an error in my application. Where is it supposed to extract too?

Comment: I have tried several other resource extractors, but to no avail... think i'm just going to use a different icon to save wasting anymore time... thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in "{Your_project_name}.{Form_name}.resources" file. Search inside the "obj" folder which is in your project folder.

Now open the command prompt of Visual Studio. We will convert this ".resources" file into a ".resx" file. We use "resgen" command here.

resgen foo.resources bar.resx

The .resx can then be added to a C# project. You can find your icon file there.